# Create list view with custom set of data in android?

Tags: android, list, listview, custom-lists

I am trying to create  `ListView` with custom data set as follows:

```
String superType = "random1";
String superTypea = "random12";
String superType12 = "random2";

String superType_amount = "child1";
String childtype_calulated = "2323";

 String superType_amount = "child2";
String childtype_calulated = "23223";

 String superType_amount = "child2";
String childtype_calulated = "amount3";
```

Now I want to create `ListView` with this set of data how to do that?

Here is the list structure...

```
row1=superType  |superType_amount |childtype_calulated 
row2=superTypea |superType_amount |childtype_calulated
row3=superType12|superType_amount |childtype_calulated
```

Is there any solution of this?

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible to do this. First, I would recommend putting your data into a collection. It would be preferable to put them into an object and then a collection of those objects. From there you can add a ListView to your main layout, define a custom layout for your list items, and populate your ListView using an ArrayAdapter.

[Here is a really good example of how you can do this well.](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) It includes examples of loading data from an external source, which you don't need.

However, if you're getting into development now I would suggest you look into RecyclerView as well. RecyclerView is new and included in the AppCompat v7 library for use on pre-Lollipop Android. A RecyclerView will be a little more complicated to implement for a simple list but is significantly more scalable and efficient. I believe it is Google's intention to replace ListView with RecyclerView entirely in the future.

[Here is a pretty simple introduction to making a list with RecyclerView.](http://techlovejump.com/android-recyclerview-to-create-list-like-view/)

---

---

EDIT

Using an ArrayAdapter with a ListView. First you need to create a model to store your data, some kind of class that you can put into a collection, for example:

```
public class Item {
    public String title;
    public String sub1;
    public String sub2;

    public void Item(String t, String s1, String s2) {
        title = t;
        sub1 = s1;
        sub2 = s2;
    }
}
```

Then you need to define the layout for the item in your list:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sub1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sub2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in you need to make your custom ArrayAdapter by extending the ArrayAdapter class:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
       super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       Item item = getItem(position);    

       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
       }

       TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
       TextView sub1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub1);
       TextView sub2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub2);

       title.setText(item.title);
       sub1.setText(item.sub1);
       sub2.setText(item.sub2);

       return convertView;
   }
}
```

Then all you need to do is create an instance of the adapter in your main class and attach your collection to it:

```
ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, data);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This should populate your ListView with all the items that you need in your list. I haven't run any of this code so there might be one or two small bugs for you to fix.

Comment: sry i am not getting how to do this? :( plz suggest

Comment: Check my edit, I gave you some code that should help you out.

Comment: Whoa great answer :)